# Multiple text-alignments in QLabel

Tags: html, qt, pyqt, text-alignment

I have a QGridLayout with QLabels in it that are displaying some values and the units to that values. For good readability I want the value to be left-aligned within the QLabel and the unit to be right-aligned.

At first I wanted to do this with QtStyleSheets but the only way I found was to change the text-alignment of the whole widget like this:

```
myLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel {qproperty-alignment: AlignRight}")
```

My second thought was to do it via HTML but there I also encountered several problems. Here is what I tried:

```
myLabel.setText("<div align=\"left\">Value<\div><div align=\"right\">Unit<\div>")
```

This does the right thing, after that the value is left-aligned and the unit right-aligned, but they are not on the same line anymore. Nevertheless it appears to me the more promising approach. Unluckily I am not very familiar with HTML. 
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you really just want go on with html in QLabel use table instead of div's. But @saeed is right, better use Qt Layouts and spacer between them.

Example with HTML:

```
myLabel.setText("<table width=\"100%\"><td width=\"50%\" align=\"left\">Value</td><td width=\"50%\" align=\"right\">Unit</td></table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use two Qlabels and a Horizontal spacer like image below ,  this is fast and you can let Qt handle whole design layout.

[image: some helpful image]